# How frequent should I query for an article so my crawler doesn't get banned?

Tags: web-crawler, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I need to download the first paragraph of every article in every major widely spoken language wikipedia is available. Preferably, in plain text with no formatting.

I found this URL:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&titles=Socrates&prop=extracts&exintro&explaintext

Unfortunately, I had to know the **title** of every article. So, I figured I could use **pageid** instead:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&pageids=25664190&prop=extracts&exintro&explaintext

Start with **pageids=0** and increment until **pageids=INT_MAX**.

For a different widely spoken language like German I can simply change the domain to **de**:

> https://de.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&pageids=4649&prop=extracts&exintro&explaintext

The final URL is:

> https://%LLD%.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&pageids=%PAGE_ID%&prop=extracts&exintro&explaintext

Where

> LLD = Low level domain of the country

> PAGE_ID = Integer

I can't make sense of data dumps and this is the simplest way I found to do the job. Since, I really don't want to get my IP banned after say 10,000 articles, how frequent should I crawl for a different PAGE_ID?

I need a metric so it can be as performant as possible.

**MAJOR EDIT**

> There is no hard and fast limit on read requests, but we ask that you
> be considerate and try not to take a site down. Most sysadmins reserve
> the right to unceremoniously block you if you do endanger the
> stability of their site.
>
> ***If you make your requests in series rather than in parallel (i.e. wait***
> ***for the one request to finish before sending a new request, such that***
> ***you're never making more than one request at the same time), then you***
> ***should definitely be fine.*** Also try to combine things into one request
> where you can (e.g. use multiple titles in a titles parameter instead
> of making a new request for each title

API FAQ states you can retrieve 50 pages per API request.

For crawling a total of 70,000,000 pageids in series of 50 pageids once every X amount of time it will take:

> (70,000,00 / 50) * 200ms = 3 days

> (70,000,00 / 50) * 500ms = 8 days

> (70,000,00 / 50) * 1sec = 16 days

***Will I definitely be fine even if choose once every 200ms?***

Comment: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Etiquette might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like practically there's enough delay in processing of the article (parsing the json and storing it somewhere or even simply storing it somewhere) so that one call after the other will never stress the servers enough.

A single valid article (full of text) takes around 250ms to complete with exchars=1200 (maximum number of characters per article).

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use the URL itself, but rather the Open Graph Tags in the Header of each page. Wikipedia has tags for `og:title`, `og:image`, and `og:type`. If you need assistance with Open Graph Protocol refer to https://ogp.me/. As for your IP ban I wouldn't really worry too much. Wikipedia is used by millions of people and unless you are using bots to do malicious activity the likely hood of getting banned is slim.

Comment: Well, I already have all I need. Point is making it performant enough so it doesn't take the whole summer to finish.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? Open graph tags do not include text extracts at the moment.